# Low frame-rate with nested transformed elements

Tags: javascript, ipad, css, webkit

I have a custom scroll view implementation. It simply works by transforming the scroll element to the left and right.

It gives a fairly decent frame-rate on mobile safari. The problem is, **as soon as I transform some of the elements that sit inside the scroller, the frame-rate suddenly drops.**

Here is the **[demo](http://ariaminaei.github.com/FastTouchAndDomExperiments/demos/metro.html)**.

If you look at it in chrome (with "Emulate Touch Events" enabled), everything moves smoothly, except for the first few moments when its uploading the textures to the GPU.

But on an iOS6 iPad, as long as there are no transformed elements in the view, movement is smooth. But if you scroll further to the right, where I have transformed a few elements with `scale3d()`, everything becomes janky. It's like its re-uploading the textures on every frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply removed all the

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
```

that were *supposed* to "force hardware acceleration."